# JS chained Promise code syntax changes the order things are running - why?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to run async processes in order using chained promises.

I started with this:

```
var dataStore = {};
DBCalls.GetAllProjects()
.then((data) => ProcessData.StoreProjects(data,dataStore))
.then(ProcessData.DoStuff(dataStore))
```

The above finished the DoStuff function before StoreProjects function. (Running in wrong order)

```
var dataStore = {};
DBCalls.GetAllProjects()
.then((data) => ProcessData.StoreProjects(data,dataStore))
.then(() => {ProcessData.DoStuff(dataStore)})
```

This ran the function in correct order.

Can anyone explain what the differences in the syntax are?

Is it because the StoreProjects Resolve is returning nothing and that the callback signatures are different?

**Extra Info:**
All functions used return promises.

Comment: you called ...DoStuff immediately in the first snippet. Of course it finishes first. You didn't wait for the first to finish before calling it.

Comment: Also, does your ProcessData.StoreProjects function return promise?

Comment: This is the reason why the argument to `.then()` should always be a function. Passing functions as arguments is the way you delay running the callback.

Comment: Because `ProcessData.DoStuff(dataStore)` is a different thing than `() => {ProcessData.DoStuff(dataStore)}`.

Comment: All functions used in the code returns promises. @KevinB Could you elaborate?  My understanding was that by using the second "then" will only happen after StoreProjects was done, but that was not the case in the first snippet.

Comment: @Bergi , so it's because of the function signature then?

Comment: Yes, the one expression produces a function that calls `DoStuff`, the other is a call to `DoStuff` itself.

Answer (score 0):

If your functions return promises, you should be using the return statement in the promise handlers if you want to wait for the promise to resolve before moving on to the next handler in the chain.

```
var dataStore = {};
return DBCalls.GetAllProjects()
  .then((data) => { return ProcessData.StoreProjects(data, dataStore); })
  .then(() => { return ProcessData.DoStuff(dataStore); })
```